# Different scrolling feature for different sections using CSS

Tags: css

I have 2 sections and one is on left other one is in right.
Now when I want to scroll up, I want left's content to be fixed and right to be scrollable
I tried position:fixed, but it didn't work and the content is coming over the right section.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
              <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSE07RTpAzIaDf5TzlGa7yP8Wz89b7SaYBnmg&usqp=CAU" alt="">
                <img src="https://govisually.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/11.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTwhK-yAdm8kWHrMrSvMVDmebxnOyu_EDz47w&usqp=CAU" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

````
.container{
    display: flex;
}

.left{
    background-color: blueviolet;
    width: 50%;
}

.right{
    background-color: rgb(43, 183, 226);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}

img{
    width:40%;
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the left section height depends on the right div. if right div content are big so left section are strech to the same as right section height. If you can sticky your left section, just add the screen height for the left section **height: 100vh;** or if you do not need to stretch the height to the bottom, just change the value of the **100vh** to **100%**. and ass the position: sticy; instead of **fixed** to the left section.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
}

.left {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    width: 50%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}

.right {
    background-color: rgb(43, 183, 226);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}

img {
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSE07RTpAzIaDf5TzlGa7yP8Wz89b7SaYBnmg&usqp=CAU" alt="">
        <img src="https://govisually.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/11.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTwhK-yAdm8kWHrMrSvMVDmebxnOyu_EDz47w&usqp=CAU" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the top:0; CSS with sticky position class; then see the output.
Add the top:0; to your .start Class.

Comment: But there is one small problem it's not that smooth, I don't want left section to move at all

Comment: change the top value as per the above space like top: 3rem; etc. and see

Comment: I did that but after that space is covered, it still move up